# Siddhi How to track what's going on inside ExecutionPlanRuntime

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, siddhi

Is there any way to track/log the inner execution of the Siddhi execution plan? Now I'm talking about vanilla Siddhi not WSO2 CEP. I didn't find any way how to turn it on. How do you debug your rules?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in Logger function of Siddhi. Please refer this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-Siddhilogger). However, this is only available after Siddhi 3.1.0